# FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication don't work on variable. How to fix?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex-spark

it's work: FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addElement(item);
but it's not:

```
public var app:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;
trace(app) //it's null
app.addElement(item);
```

Error: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Why it's not working via variable?

**Edit:**
it's working in function like that:

```
private function bekleticiEkle():void{
    var app:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;
    trace(app) //it's testClientApp0
    var item:Label = new Label;
    item.text = "Test";
    app.addElement(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. We must define it when application is created. So first, use it:

```
private var app:Object;
protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    app = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;
}
private function doSomething():void
 trace(app)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line at

`public var app:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;`

it should be

`public var app:Object = new object();
 app = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;`